# Database, How to manage item price in database

Tags: database-design

I have two table in my application, one is "item" and "itemprice" and these are already created by a previous developer. The itemprice table contain fields like, unitOfSale , itemPoint, itemSalePrice and itemPurchasePrice, tax. There are some fields those are duplicate in item and itmPrice table.

Can i merge itemPrice table in item table. will it do any negative imapact on architecture,

Do I need to keep the history of itemprice when it changes?

If I need to keep history of price then which architecture should i follow ? one table (merged table) or two table?

Comment: It's quite hard to tell what impact it will have without details of exactly what feilds each table contains, and the database management software you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Using **two tables** is best to handle the price details of items and by merging two tables you may face some issues in your project you have to change all the queries / codes which are all involved by item and itemprice tables.

**To your 2nd question:**
Keeping two tables 1 for product details and another one for product price details.
**Map the primary key** of item table in itemprice table **as foreign key** is the best and easy way to handle the price history.